# What gives me mutagen?

Tags: swarm-simulator

I've just unlocked the mutagen tab, and I have about 34,000 mutagen. However, I can't work out how this number is derived. I'm assuming it's based on some rate or other, but I've tried boosting a few and can't work out which one it's linked to.

How do I earn more mutagen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gain mutagen at 20% chance (increases with level of **mutagen frequency**) every time you upgrade hatchery past 40 and expansion past 80.

This 20% chance is seeded, and recorded with your save, so 'savescumming' (reloading the game to try again) doesn't work.